# OP_ADD operation in bitcoin script for integers greater than 128 in java

Tags: script, bitcoinj, java

I want to execute a simple series of instructions to implement a bitcoin script in java using bitcoinj API. All I am looking for is performing arithmetic operations for negative integers or integers greater than 128. An example bitcoin script for the task would look like this:

`150 120 OP_ADD 270 OP_CHECKNUMEQUAL`

This script should return True eventually. To implement this in java, to push integer values like 150, 270 etc i have to first convert them to byte arrays. I have followed answers given in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936857/convert-integer-into-byte-array-java but none of them works in here probably because of differently defined arithmetic operations in bitcoinj API script. Can anyone please help me in this.

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far?

Answer (score 1):

you should use Litte-endian encoding. if the highest bit is set (range 128-255, 32768-65535 and so on) you should append the zero byte to mark these bytes as positive number.

So, `150(dec)` will be encoded as `9600`

`270(dec)` will be encoded as `0e01`